# firebase deploy to custom region for scheduled functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I successfully managed to deploy my `https.onCall()` cloud functions on a specific server location with

```
functions.region("europe-west6")
.https.onCall((data, context) => ...
```

But when I tried to specify a location for scheduled function:

```
   exports.getItems = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 6 * * *')
  .region("europe-west6")
  .timeZone('Europe/Zurich')
  .onRun(async (context) => {
```

I receive:

TypeError: functions.pubsub.schedule(...).region is not a function

I wonder if this functionality (defining custom deploy region) is not available for scheduled functions...

(btw deploying the scheduled function worked without the `.region()` parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.region()` exists on imported `functions` SDK itself and not on the [ScheduleBuilder](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_pubsub.schedulebuilder) returned by `.schedule()`, try this:

```
exports.getItems = functions.region("europe-west6")
  // after .region(''), similar to the HTTP function
  .pubsub.schedule('0 6 * * *')  
  .timeZone('Europe/Zurich')
  .onRun(async (context) => {

  })
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much! how could I miss that..